# Regex for xy positions

Tags: regex

I need a regex to check if an input is a valid XY position.
Allowed positions: A1 - A11, B1 - B11, C1 - C11

Thus far I have this: `^[A-C, a-c]{1}([1-9])$`

It works for all inputs A1 - A9, B1 - B9 and C1 - C9

It doesn't work for A10, A11, B10, B11, C10 and C11

Anyone an idea? :)

Comment: Try [`^[A-Ca-c](?:[1-9]|1[01])$`](https://regex101.com/r/PvOODS/1)

Comment: [Check your regex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/QuL2HeEjileq5dCu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[1-9]` character class only matches a single digit from `1` to `9` thus you cannot expect it to match `10` or `11` char sequences.

The `[A-C, a-c]{1}` pattern (equal to `[A-C, a-c]`) can match a space and `,`, you need to remove those chars.

Use

```
^[A-Ca-c](?:[1-9]|1[01])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PvOODS/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Ca-c]` - `A`, `B`, `C`, `a`, `b` or `c`
- `(?:[1-9]|1[01])` - either a digit from `1` to `9` or `10` or `11` numbers
- `$` - end of string